# Как вставить число из .txt файла в переменную?

Tags: python

Если сохранить переменную  money в .txt файл, а потом попробавать его загрузить, вместо цифр будет белеберда. Как это испраить?

```
money = 50

while True:
    a = input('выберите действие(save, load, money): ')
    
    if a == 'save':
        name_of_file = input("Придумайте название сохранению: ")
        completeName = name_of_file + ".txt"
        file1 = open(completeName , "w")
            
        toFile = str(money)
            
        file1.write(toFile)
            
        file1.close()
        print("Прогресс успешно сохранён!")
        
    if a == 'load':
        loadcode = input("Введите название вашего сохранения(Добавьте в конце .txt): ")
        save = open(loadcode)
        money = save
        
    if a == 'money':
        print(money)
```

Comment: мало открыть файл, надо "прочитать" его содержимое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
money = 50

while True:
    a = input('выберите действие(save, load, money, stop): ')

    if a == 'save':
        name_of_file = input("Придумайте название сохранению: ")
        completeName = name_of_file + ".txt"
        file1 = open(completeName , "w")
        
        toFile = str(money)
        
        file1.write(toFile)
        
        file1.close()
        print("Прогресс успешно сохранён!")
    
    elif a == 'load':
        loadcode = input("Введите название вашего сохранения(Добавьте в конце .txt): ")
        save = open(loadcode)
        money = save.read()
        save.close()
    
    elif a == 'money':
        print(money)
    elif a == 'stop':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os # Импортируем модуль для дополнительных возможностей
def save(save): # Создаём функцию сохранения
    save += '.txt' # Получаем имя файла сохранения
    with open(save, 'w') as f: # Открываем файл
        f.write(str(money)) # Записываем
def load(save): # Создаём функцию загрузки
    save += '.txt' # Получаем имя файла загрузки
    with open(save, 'r') as f: # Открываем файл
        money = int(f.read()) # Читаем и сразу делаем числом
    return money # Возвращаем в значении функции - переменную money

money = 50

while True:
    a = input('Выберите действие (save, load, money): ')

    if a == 'save':
        save_name = input('Название нового сохранения: '); save_name += '.txt' # Узнаём имя сохранения, после чего получаем имя файла
        if save_name in os.listdir('Папка с сохранениями'): # Если такой файл уже есть в папке сохранений. (Метод os.listdir() даёт список со всеми файлами указанной папки)
            print('Такое сохранение уже есть!')
        else: # Иначе
            save(file_name) # Создаём новое сохранение

    elif a == 'load':
        save_name = input('Название сохранения: '); file_name += '.txt' # Узнаём имя сохранения после чего получаем имя файла сохранения
        if save_name not in os.listdir('Папка с сохранения'): # Если такого сохранения нет в папке сохранений
            print('Такого сохранения нет.')
        else: # Иначе
            money = load(save_name) # money будет равен тому, что вернёт нам load()

    elif a == 'money':
        print(money)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь всё работает как надо!

Comment: Не забывайте помечать галочкой ответы, которые помогли